# How to choose elements for return from key function(XSLT)

Tags: xml, xslt, key, func

### My XML file look like:

```
<Geometry>
   <Shapes>
    <Shape id="b1" author-id="a1">
        <width>First</width>
        <height>Shape</height>
        <color>Color</color>
     <Shape id="b2" author-id="a2">
        <width>Second</width>
        <height>Shape</height>
        <color>Color</color>
    </Shape>
</Shapes>
<Authors>
    <Author id="b1">
        <name>Andrew</name>
        <secondname>Coldwater</secondname>
        <tel>978-3-16-148410-0</tel>
    </Author>
    <Author id="b2">
        <name>Andrew</name>
        <secondname>Coolwater</secondname>
        <tel>9781-140-201</tel>
    </Author>
</Author>
```

### when im using

```
<xsl:key name="exampleName" match="Author" use="@id"/>
```

### and

```
  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('exampleName', @author-id)" />
```

### on on return i have all of Author's properties. What i need to do to receive only name and second name. Maybe its trivial question but i cant find answer... Or i dont know how to ask :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a template to match the `Author` elements from `<xsl:apply-templates select="key('exampleName', @author-id)" />`.

Like

```
<xsl:template match="Author">
    <xsl:value-of select="name" />
    <xsl:value-of select="secondname" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank u so much :)